# Does GlusterFS require XFS or can it work with other file systems?

Tags: glusterfs

I am trying to install GlusterFS and I see all the instructions utilize the creation of an XFS mount point, is it a limitation that GlusterFS requires XFS?  Can it work with vfat or ntfs mounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GlusterFS works on any filesystem which supports extended attributes (EA).

An example is [Gluster on ZFS](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Gluster%20On%20ZFS/)

Comment: Is there a link that shows what kind of file systems support extended attributes?

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) "In Linux, the ext2, ext3, ext4, JFS, Squashfs, Yaffs2, ReiserFS, Reiser4, XFS, Btrfs, OrangeFS, Lustre, OCFS2 1.6 and F2FS[8] filesystems support extended attributes (abbreviated xattr) when enabled in the kernel configuration"